# Visibility/Invisibility of label in .cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have some code like follows:

```
if {
  this.showhide.ImageUrl = "../common/images/hide-icon.png";
  this.showhide.AlternateText = "Hide SearchBar";
  this.searchBar.Visible = false;
  Session["showHideImage"] = "hide";
  ScreenProjectSearch ProjSearch = CurrentProjectSearch;
  lblTypeOfSearch.Text = "Search results are based on";
  string typeOfSearch = string.Empty;

  if (CurrentProjectSearch != null)
  {
    //lblTypeOfSearch.Text = "Search results are based on";

    if (CurrentProjectSearch.IsFileName)
      typeOfSearch += " Filename " + ProjSearch.TextSearch.Trim();
    if (CurrentProjectSearch.IsDescription)
      typeOfSearch += " Description " + ProjSearch.TextSearch.Trim();
    if (CurrentProjectSearch.IsPartNumber)
      typeOfSearch += " PartNumber " + ProjSearch.TextSearch.Trim();
    if (CurrentProjectSearch.IsState)
    {
      if (CurrentProjectSearch.IsDevelopment)
        typeOfSearch += " Development State ";
      if (CurrentProjectSearch.IsValidation)
        typeOfSearch += " Validation State ";
      if (CurrentProjectSearch.IsValidationPendingApproval)
        typeOfSearch += " ValidationPendingApproval State ";
      if (CurrentProjectSearch.IsPilot)
        typeOfSearch += " Pilot State ";
      if (CurrentProjectSearch.IsFactory)
        typeOfSearch += " Factory State ";
      if (CurrentProjectSearch.IsCancel)
        typeOfSearch += " Cancel State ";
    }
    if (CurrentProjectSearch.IsDate)
      typeOfSearch += " Created Date From: " + ProjSearch.FromDate + " To: " + ProjSearch.ToDate;
    if (CurrentProjectSearch.IsPromoteDate)
      typeOfSearch += " Promoted Date From: " + ProjSearch.FromPromoteDate + " To: " + ProjSearch.ToPromoteDate;
    if (CurrentProjectSearch.IsCreatedBy)
      typeOfSearch += " Created By: " + ProjSearch.CreatedBy.ToString();
    if (CurrentProjectSearch.IsProjectIDs)
      typeOfSearch += " PrjoectIds: " + ProjSearch.ProjectIDs;
    if (CurrentProjectSearch.IsWorkFlow)
    {
      if (CurrentProjectSearch.IsMdiagsNormal)
        typeOfSearch += " WorkFlow: " + "Mdiags Normal";
      if (CurrentProjectSearch.IsMdiagsTestEngineer)
        typeOfSearch += " WorkFlow: " + "Mdiags TestEngineer";
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(typeOfSearch))
    {
      lblTypeOfSearch.Text += typeOfSearch;
      lblTypeOfSearch.Visible = true;
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to display this `lblTypeOfSearch` in `Page_Load` if some text is appended to it when the `typeOfSearch` is not null. If I check the value os `lblTypeOfSearch` in `Page_Load` it is displaying null there. How can I make use of this variable there to display?

Comment: Just debug the behemoth and see what's actually going on...

Comment: This code is on button click. Label gets added with text in button click event. If I want to use the same text again how can I use it in Page load method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time the user clicks on something and isn't handled on client-side, there's a request going to the server and it returns a NEW page with its NEWLY instantiated code-behind. So, if you want to persist data during postbacks, returns to the page etc., you need to store it somewhere first (session, db, whatever...) and then you can access that in Page_Load.

Remember, websites are stateless.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see, your code must work fine, may you see cached result, in that case you can press ctrl + F5 keys to see your new code result.
If you want can access to your text both in button click and form load, you can declare your string variable as global (out of these methodes).

Comment: Global variables? YUCK! They're evil enough, but to promote them in web programming? Definitely a no-no sir!

Comment: Thanks, but in web programming we can have same functionality with global variables in javascript. Or if we had to do this server side, we can make an extra hidden input.

Comment: How would javascript persist data when loading a new page?? (that's when Page_Load is called)

Comment: Yes, if page does a refresh, javascript has no data from contents of before refresh. I meant an alternative scenario that does not refresh the page.